# How to trim two words from right of a string

Tags: tcl

I want to remove two words from right of a string.

For example:

```
set str "sachin is the pride of india"
```

I need to remove `india` and `of` from right and there should be no space after that.

I have tried using `string trimright`.

Answer (score 2):

The `string trimright` command is exactly the wrong tool for this; it treats its trim argument as a *set of characters* to remove, not a literal. The simplest way of doing this is with `lreplace`, *provided the string doesn't contain list metacharacters* and you don't care about the number of spaces.

```
set shortened [lreplace $str end-1 end]
```

If you need to do it *reliably*, **regular expressions are the tool of choice**.

```
set shortened [regsub {\s*\S+\s+\S+\s*$} $str ""]
```

Use `regsub` for this. Please.

Comment: can you please help me in understanding set shortened [regsub {\s*\S+\s+\S+\s*$} $str ""] expression...

Comment: May I ask what is the difference between the two? Or is that simply a matter of potential braces in the string which might interpret one or more words as elements in the list `$str`?

Comment: @GauravKumar `regsub` will perform a substitution to `$str` and replace what matched the regular expression by nothing (in other words, remove what is matched). The regex `\s*\S+\s+\S+\s*$` matches in order: any spaces, non-space characters (first word), more spaces, more non-space characters (second word), any spaces and end of the string (`$` matches only at the end so it ensures the last two words (sequence of non-space characters) are being replaced).